# Windows Explorer Subversion File Size

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, svn

I have a subversion repository that I committed to the server. I then checked it out to verify that every works properly. Now my local copy if I highlight the directory says `Size: 2.87GB`

If I right click on the same directory I highlighted: properties -> general tab - the size shows `5.74GB`

Notice how `2.87*2 = 5.74`- weird right?

I found [subversion uses libz to compress binary differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458182/does-svn-compress-the-binary-content) but if this is my "first version" of the files then compression should not be the reason for the sizes showing differently.

Why are they different, what is the actual size of my repository???

Answer (score 0):

You can't allocate less than allocation unit size per file (4K for NTFS). For extremely exotic case (a lot of small files) physical space will be dramatically bigger, than logical space

For one of my repos (hundreds of files of *Some*K every)

```
Size: 8.13 MB
Size on disk: 31.6 MB
```

Comment: I understand Size and Size on disk will be different. That is not what I am asking.